# Inserting greater than or equal symbol in to an iText PDF, ie >=

Tags: java, itext

Does anyone know an easy way to include the greater than or equal symbol in an iText PDF document without resorting to custom fonts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2265/index.htm) for this character. Also make sure that the char is included in the font you use.

```
document.add( new Paragraph("\u2265"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code for the same. It's work for me.

//symbol for greater or equal then

```
public void process() throws DocumentException, IOException {
            String dest = "/home/ashok/ashok/tmp/hello.pdf"; 
            
            BaseFont bfont = BaseFont.createFont(
                        "/home/ashok/ashok/fonts/Cardo-Regular.ttf",
                        BaseFont.IDENTITY_H,
                        BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
              Font font = new Font(bfont, 12);
             
            try {
                 Document document=new Document();
                 PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new 
                 FileOutputStream("/home/ashok/ashok/tmp/hello.pdf"));
                 document.open();
                    Chunk chunk = new Chunk("\u2265");
                    Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Mathematical Operators are ",font);
                    p.add(chunk);
                    document.add(p);
                    p = new Paragraph("  ",font);
                    chunk = new Chunk("\u2264");
                    p.add(chunk);
                    
                    document.add(p);
                    document.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         
        }
```